# Regex doesn't save match in variable

Tags: php, regex

I got URLs to different Youtube channels stored in my database. I am now trying to loop through all of them and check whether they still exist with the following code:

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    preg_match("/([^/]+$)/", $page['url'], $channelId);

    $channel = get_data('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id='.$channelId[0].'&key='.$site['yt_api']);

    $channel = json_decode($channel, true);

    echo $channelId[0];
    echo $channel[pageInfo][totalResults];

    break;
}
```

The problem is that this test code doesn't print out `$channelId[0]` but only `$channel[pageInfo][totalResults]` which is `0` in this case due to some error with my regex. Could someone point out my error please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) or escape the forward slash.

```
preg_match('~[^/]+$~', $page['url'], $channelId);
```